# No delay in function call

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, logging, random

For a random  delayed execution of a function i used following code in a for loop with index i decreasing for each iteration and randomtime is an array of random values:

`threading.Timer(int(random.random()*20)+i, postit,[replydata]).start()`

but on examining the log I see that postit function is not delayed at all and it just executes all timer calls to postit almost instantly.

So how to really randomly delay each function call without using timer.sleep as it freezes the app.

On seeing the log following arbitary order timestamps are seen, the logging is done inside posit function, BEGIN is the start of the program:

```
2015-04-24 19:06:20,775 INFO 
2015-04-24 19:06:20,782 INFO
2015-04-24 19:06:21,749 INFO 
.
:
2015-04-24 19:06:25,845 INFO BEGIN
```

Code sample:

```
def startsession():
with session() as c:
    preq=c.post('...', data=payloadlogin,headers = headers)
    response=c.post('...',data=payloaddata,headers = headers)
    j=json.loads(response.text)
    logger.info('BEGIN'+str(c.cookies.items()))

    #print j
    for i in range(len(j['data'])-1,0,-1) :
        part=j['data'][i]['body']
        code=j['data'][i]['code']
        pics=''
        for t in range(len(j['data'][i]['pics'])):
            pics=pics+j['data'][i]['pics'][t]['name']+' , '


        rep=getreply(part,pics)
        e=(code,part, pics,rep)


        if rep!='':
            replydata['cod']=code
            replydata['rep']=rep
            replydata['pos']=int(random.random()*10)
            def postreply(replydata):
                represponse=c.post('...',data=replydata,headers = headers)
                logger.info(str(e) +" "+str(represponse))


            threading.Timer(int(random.random()*20), postreply,[replydata]).start()
            print i+replydata['pos']
        else:
            logger.info(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startsession()
```

Comment: `it just executes all of them when called.` - What do you mean by that?

Comment: all function calls are executed in one go , no delay is seen, @thefourtheye

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`Timer`'s definition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer)

```
threading.Timer(interval, function, args=[], kwargs={})
```

you need to pass the function object as the second parameter and a list of arguments to be passed to the function. So, you need to write it like this

```
threading.Timer(int(random.random()*10)+i, postit, [data]).start()
```

Now, `postit` is the function to be called and `[data]` is the arguments to be passed to the `postit` function when invoked.

You can also use a tuple as arguments, like this

```
threading.Timer(int(random.random()*10)+i, postit, (data,)).start()
```

Comment: yes but this does not solve the problem asked, all calls are immediately executed still

Comment: @stackit Can you please post a reproducible sample? Also the actual code which you tried.

Comment: the code runs in a for loop thus triggering the timer each time.

Comment: I can confirm that thefourtheye's implementation works as expected in a simple loop, there must be something else going on in your code.

Comment: the delays are like 7,2,6,8, seconds and the pogram just runs in 2-3  sec and ends!

Comment: @stackit Can you show the actual code or at least a miminal reproducible example?

Comment: @stackit It doesn't look like there is any problem in your code. Can you try to reproduce the problem with something like [this](http://ideone.com/cRKO2f)?